# Batch file to zip and upload thru ftp

Tags: batch-file, ftp, backup

im setting a backup for my pc, can someone help me set a batch file that zip the users folder rename it to date and upload it thru ftp to a server.
Tried some example online with 7zip but the dont seem to work.

thanks

Found this to zip and rename

```
@ECHO OFF
Title testizarc.bat
REM updated 10/22/2014
REM Replace space in hour with zero if it's less than 10
SET hr=%time:~0,2%
IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%
REM This sets the date like this: mm-dd-yr-hrminsecs1/100secs
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-    %hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
REM Use IZArc to Zip files in folder c:\testzip and place the zip archive 
REM in C:\testmove
ECHO.
ECHO Zipping all files in C:\testzip and moving archive to c:\testmove
ECHO.
izarcc -a -cx "C:\testmove\xxxx_%TODAY%.zip" "C:\testzip\*.*"
ECHO.
ECHO Delete the files in orginal folder
DEL "C:\testzip\*.*"
PAUSE
:end
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what, specifically, didn't work? Was the zip not created? Was the zip created but the file wasn't uploaded? Was the wrong file uploaded? Show us the code you were working with.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples has some really good examples. Otherwise you really do need to give us more information about where you are stuck as there are plenty of examples in this forum already for date manipulation, etc.

Comment: Found this to zip and rename, but it doesnt work